# fetching the values of respective key in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
      $details= array(

             "Name" => array (
                                 0 => "John",
                                 1 => "Harry",
                                 2 => "Thomas"
                              ),
             "Profession" => array 
                               (
                                 0 => "Painter",
                                 1 => "Designer",
                                 2 => "Programmer"
                               )
            );
```

I am using ajax to fetch the data and I want to fetch it in such a way that when the key is name only values corresponding to key name should echo in the desired place.

Here you dont have to show how to fetch via ajax just let me know how to fetch the data when key = name.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Can you give an example of desired in put and corresponding desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($details[$name]))
    echo json_encode($details[$name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/function.array-column) for this

```
print_r(array_column($details,0)); //Fetching values by key.
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Painter
)
```